# Mathematica - can I define a block of code using a single variable?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

It has been a while since I've used Mathematica, and I looked all throughout the help menu.  I think one problem I'm having is that I do not know what exactly to look up.  I have a block of code, with things like appending lists and doing basic math, that I want to define as a single variable.

My goal is to loop through a sequence and when needed I wanted to call a block of code that I will be using several times throughout the loop.  I am guessing I should just put it all in a loop anyway, but I would like to be able to define it all as one function.

It seems like this should be an easy and straightforward procedure.  Am I missing something simple?

Comment: Welcome to the StackExchange network! For future Mathematica-related questions, you can consider asking on [Mathematica.SE](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/).  Most of the Mathematica-related activity has moved there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not entirely clear, but I interpret that you want something like this:

```
facRand[] :=
 ({b, x} = Last@FactorInteger[RandomInteger[1*^12]]; Print[b])
```

Now every time `facRand[]` is called a new random integer is factored, global variables `b` and `x` are assigned, and the value of `b` is printed.  This could also be done with `Function`:

```
Clear[facRand]

facRand =
 ({b, x} = Last@FactorInteger[RandomInteger[1*^12]]; Print[b]) &
```

This is also called with `facRand[]`. This form is standard, and allows addressing or passing the symbol `facRand` without triggering evaluation.

Answer (score 1):

This is the basic format for a function definition in Mathematica.

```
    myFunc[par1_,par2_]:=Module[{localVar1,localVar2}, 
statement1; statement2; returnStatement ]
```